# remove table tr when click btn jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, append

I am creating a add and remove function in jQuery when `minus btn [remove_button]` will click. but it not working.
I am appending the `td` when which `plus btn [add_button]` it works but how I achieve for deletion method.

My code is below, I am fresh in jQuery and hoping if I am wrong you buddy developers will help to fix the issue.

```js
var maxField = 5;
var x = 1;
$('.add_button').click(function() {
  if (x < maxField) {
    x++;
    newrow = '<tr class="ok"><td><select class="form-control" name="product_name[]" id="product_id" required><option value="14563">Product 1</option><option value="96547">Product 2</option><option value="965489">Product 3</option></select></td><td><input type="tel" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Enter Quantity" /></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove_button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></td></tr>';
    var rowspan = parseInt($('.field_data').attr('rowspan')) + 1;
    $('.field_data').attr('rowspan', rowspan);
    $('.complaint_table tr:eq(3)').after(newrow);
  }
});

$(".complaint_table").on("click", ".remove_button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this.tr).remove();
  x--;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered complaint_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Company:</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Company" />
      </td>
      <td>Company RegDate:</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="complaint_table">
      <td rowspan="10" class="field_data">Products<span style="color: red; font-size: 14px;"> *</span>:</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="product_name[]">
          <option value="14563">Product 1</option>
          <option value="96547">Product 2</option>
          <option value="965489">Product 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="number" maxlength="2" minlength="1" name="quantity[]" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success add_button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Well, @RoryMcCrossan answer will solve your problem with deleting rows, but just for the record I also think your add method won't work as expected. At least with your current provided code, because there is no 4th `tr` *(`... tr:eq(3)`)* in the table cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `this` in the `.remove_button` click handler refers to the DOM element. They do not have a `tr` property.

Instead to get a reference to the parent `tr` element to the clicked button use `closest()`:

```
$(".complaint_table").on("click", ".remove_button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  x--;
});
```